# .on('click') with ajax content from another ajax content

Tags: ajax, jquery

Trying to get an event triggered with ajax content whose parent elements were also ajax loaded.

```
<div id="content"><!-- NOT ajax-loaded -->
    <div id="location"> <!-- #location IS ajax-loaded -->
        <div id="add_location> <!-- #add_location IS ajax-loaded from a #location event -->

            <input type="text" id="add_location_city_example" />
            <input type="text" id="add_location_state_example" />

            <input type="submit" id="add_location_confirm" />

       </div>
    </div>
</div>


$(function(){
  $('#content').on('click', '#add_location_confirm', function(){
    console.log('debug 1');
    add_location();
    // will not be called
  });

  $('#location').on('click', '#add_location_confirm', function() {
      console.log('debug 2');
      // will not be called either
      add_location();
  });
});
```

If I have onclick="add_location()" and function add_location() { console.log('debug 3); } in my .js then it will obviously be called BUT I then cannot get $('#add_location_city_example').val() because none of it will be in the dom.

NOTE: using 1.9.1

Comment: Does `console.log('debug 1');` work?

Comment: yea, I'm using chrome and console.log works.  I use it extensively for debugging in Chrome and have never had a problem with it

Comment: Well no, I mean does it actually log output, because two lines after it you said "// will not be called" so I'm trying to figure out if the console.log works but then output stops or not.

Comment: EDIT:oh... no, I'm actually not leaving comments in my testing code.  It doesn't have to do with my //'s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using this for a while, makes it much easier to handle situations like you are describing + there is only one even assignment for pretty much all clicks on the page, including elements that will appear on the page in the future:

```
$(document).bind('click', function (e) {
   var target = $(e.target);
   if (target.is('#content')) {
      e.preventDefault();
      // do whatever
   } else if (target.is('#location')) {
      e.preventDefault();
      // do whatever else
   }
});
```

or in your case it would probably be more like this:

```
$(document).bind('click', function (e) {
   var target = $(e.target);
   if (target.is('#add_location_confirm')) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (target.closest('#location').length == 0) { // not yet have location injected via ajax
          // do something
      } else {
          // location has been injected, do something else
      }
});
```